# oracle how to shorten case with complex operation

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I often run into the situation that I have quite complex operations that sometimes have to be processed further with a case.

It looks pretty ugly and has lots of redundant code in it if I use it the usual way.

Lets say.

```
select 
    case when (1+1) > 0  then (1+1) else null end 
from dual
```

That is my current usage of case.

Lets assume that (1+1) is my complex operation that may took several lines of code. If it matches the WHEN clause then I just want exactly that return value from the clause without having to repeat myself in the THEN part. 
Because that will lead to pretty ugly and blown statements.

Is there a way to write it with having the (1+1) part only a single time in the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I usually prefer to do such work in a CTE or subquery, sometimes that makes the query even more complicated.  Here is a "simpler" method:

```
select nullif(greatest(1 + 1, 0), 0)
from dual;
```

The `greatest()` will return 0 for 0 or `NULL` values (equivalent to the condition in the `case`.  The `nullif()` returns `NULL` for 0 or negative values.

Comment: ok that was enough to fix my problem in my current situation. And this is the kind of appoach I was hoping for. So i guess its all about knowledge of function combinations to achive what a need. Thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Move the code to a function. You can even have the function return null to eliminate the case statement entirely!

```
create or replace function complex_code
return number
is
  l_return number;
begin
  ... complex calculations ...
  ... more complex processing ...
  ... assign result of complex processing to l_number ...

  if l_number > 0
  then
    return l_number;
  else
    return null;
  end if;
end complex_code;
```

In your query:

```
select complex_code
from dual;
```

Comment: that would be an approach but i guess i have to do a lot or work on my structure and i was hoping for the more straigth forward solution

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a common table expression:

```
with t1 as (
  select 1+1 as complex_operation
  from ...
)
select case 
         when complex_operation > 0 then complex_operation 
         else null 
       end 
from t1
```

Comment: as far as i know i dont have access to the tables from the statement within the witch statement right ?

Comment: @ZSchneidi: you can expose all columns you want in the `WITH` statement to the outer query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, my bad ... actually works.